# Can ndiswrapper be used for things other than wireless drivers?

Tags: drivers, devices, ndiswrapper

I have never used Ndiswrapper for wireless drivers but i have used to get flash 32bit working on a 64bin system. My question is can it be used for other kinds of drivers for peripheral devices such as printers, mice or USB cameras, things of such nature. If if not why?

Comment: Are there alternatives like Ndiswrapper for sound cards?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Flash you used `NSpluginwrapper` which is an entirely different beast.

ndiswrapper only covers the NDIS ([Network Driver Interface Specification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Driver_Interface_Specification)) so as the name suggests, it's only good for network cards where Windows drivers follow this specification.

It's not going to help you with anything else.

Comment: So that means `ndiswrapper` applies to wired network cards as well?

Comment: Oh and what does `NS` stand for?

Comment: Re wired: Yes but most ethernet cards have native drivers (I assume because more servers use them so there's more Linux demand). Re `NS`: I always assumed it was NetScape **edit** and [Mozilla seem to suggest the same](http://plugindoc.mozdev.org/linux-amd64.html#nswrapper)

Comment: thx for clearing it up :)